# What is the fixed "p" percentage I should increase my investments every month to reach a target

Tags: integration, applications

I have been learning about SIP. The gist of it is that you invest on regular basis like monthly or quarterly.

The basic example is that you invest 100 every month so it looks like.

```
  0+100=100
100+100=200 (100% increase in invested money since last month)
200+100=300 (50% increase in invested money since last month)
300+100=400 (33% increase in invested money since last month)
400+100=500 (25% increase in invested money since last month)
```

Personally, I am more interested in keeping the percent increase in invested money constant every month while increasing the actually invested money. So something like that:

```
  0+100=100
100+50 =150 (50% increase in invested money since last month)
150+75 =225 (50% increase in invested money since last month)
225+112=337 (50% increase in invested money since last month)
```

Now for the math part:

I have `y` as initial capital which needs to be invested slowly over a period of `t` months. Along with `y`, I also want to increase my investment by fixed `x` every month. The capital I will invest on my first month will be `a`. My question is what should be `p` percentage of increase every month, so that at the end of `t` period, my total invested money is `y + t*x`.

Any example with values which I determined by brute-force:

```
y (Initial Capital)=500
x (Monthly investment)=100
t (Time period)=5
a (Initial Investment)=150

Here the percentage `p` is 14.5% because 150+171+196+225+257 = ~1000 (y + x*t)
```

Comment: Just checking that I understand this.  In the first month you invest $x$.  In the second, you invest  $(1+p)x$.  In the third month, you invest $(1+p)^2x$ and so on.  Is that correct?

Comment: @saulspatz I used `a` in my example instead of `x` to denote that, but yes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $a$ be the initial monthly investment, $p$ the rate at which the investments increase.  Then the amount invested in month $m$ is $a(1+p)^{m-1}$ and the total amount invested after $t$ deposits is $$\sum_{m=0}^{t-1}a(1+p)^{m}$$  This is a geometric progression whose sum is $$a\frac{(1+p)^t-1}p$$  You can set this equal to the desired amount, and solve for $p$, since $a$ and $t$ are known.

There isn't a simple closed-form solution, so you will have to solve the equation numerically.

Comment: I assume it's equal to `y+ x*t`. But what if `t` is a big number like 12 months which is most likely my situation, is there is any luck for me?

Comment: Is there any math trick to get approx value if not exact one?

Comment: What are some sample values for $y,a,x,t$? I don't understand the distinction between $x$ and $a$ in the question.

Comment: `x` is the saving from my salary I will invest every month. `a` is just the first-month investment which I picked randomly and will serve as a starting point.

Comment: But I think your answer is correct. It will return exactly what I need. Only problem is finding a quick approx value for a large `t`.

Comment: I'll write you a little script to compute the answer.  Give me a few minutes.

Comment: If you mean a brute-force script in a programming language, there is no need to waste your time. I am a programmer myself and quickly program something too.

Comment: I didn't mean brute force; I was planning to use Newton's method.  But brute-force will work fine for this problem, so I'll leave it to you.